# How to subtract values from two different nested dictionaries?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have two dicts as below:

```
> type(dict1)
  <class 'dict1'>
> dict1
{'index1': {'output': [{'quant': 27587.2, 'var1': 20, 'var2': 5, 'list1': {}}]},  
 'index2': {'output': [{'quant': 29795.9, 'var1': 22, 'var2': 5, 'list1': {}}]}
}

> type(dict2)
  <class 'dict2'>
> dict2
{'index1': {'output': [{'quant': 46587.2, 'var1': 20, 'var2': 5, 'list1': {}}]},  
 'index2': {'output': [{'quant': 39795.9, 'var1': 22, 'var2': 5, 'list1': {}}]}
}
```

The output needs to subtract `'quant'` in `dict1` from `dict2` for the corresponding `'index`' and `return` the output:

```
> output
{'index1': {'output': [{'quant': 19000, 'var1': 20, 'var2': 5, 'list1': {}}]},  
 'index2': {'output': [{'quant': 10000, 'var1': 22, 'var2': 5, 'list1': {}}]}
}
```

I am able to do for simple dictionaries but not for the nested dicts as above.  Can anyone suggest a way to do this in python?

```
d1 = {'a': 10, 'b': 9, 'c': 8, 'd': 7}
d2 = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'e': 2}
d3 = {}

for k, v in d1.items():
   d3[k] = v - d2.get(k, 0) 

 print(d3)
 {'c': 5, 'b': 7, 'a': 9, 'd': 7}
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: [I downvoted your question because no attempt was made](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt).

Comment: What about the other values in the two dicts, like `'var1'`, `'list1'`, etc — what values for them end up in the result?

Comment: they will remain the same in both dictionaries as shown in the example, original values are returned in the output. only 'quant' is required to be subtracted.

Comment: The output is a single dictionary created from the given two. In your example the values for `'var1'`, `'list1'` in the two input dicts do happen to be the same, but generally speaking that might not be the case — so you need to specify what should happen when that is the case.

Comment: 'var1', 'var2' and 'list1' will have same values in both dictionaries for same key (here index) i.e. for index1, 'var1', 'var2' and 'list1' are same in both dict1 and dict2 and likewise for index2, var1', 'var2' and 'list1' are same in both dict1 and dict2. So only 'quant' need to be subtracted and 'var1', 'var2' and 'list1' should be original values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```py
out = {}
for k2, v2 in dict2.items():
    out.setdefault(k2, {})["output"] = [
        {
            **v2["output"][0],
            "quant": v2["output"][0]["quant"] - dict1[k2]["output"][0]["quant"],
        }
    ]


print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
{
    "index1": {
        "output": [
            {"quant": 18999.999999999996, "var1": 20, "var2": 5, "list1": {}}
        ]
    },
    "index2": {
        "output": [{"quant": 10000.0, "var1": 22, "var2": 5, "list1": {}}]
    },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since floating point math is being done, the difference must be rounded to produce the result wanted.

```
from pprint import pp

dict1 = {'index1': {'output': [{'quant': 27587.2, 'var1': 20, 'var2': 5, 'list1': {}}]},
         'index2': {'output': [{'quant': 29795.9, 'var1': 22, 'var2': 5, 'list1': {}}]}}

dict2 = {'index1': {'output': [{'quant': 46587.2, 'var1': 20, 'var2': 5, 'list1': {}}]},
         'index2': {'output': [{'quant': 39795.9, 'var1': 22, 'var2': 5, 'list1': {}}]}}

diff_dict = {}
for (key, value) in dict1.items():
    diff_dict[key] = dict2[key]  # Copy everything associated with key in second dict.
    # Replace 'quant` with rounded difference between value in second and first dict.
    diff_dict[key]['output'][0]['quant'] = round(dict2[key]['output'][0]['quant'] -
                                                      value['output'][0]['quant'], 1)

pp(diff_dict, compact=True)
```

Output:

```
{'index1': {'output': [{'quant': 19000.0, 'var1': 20, 'var2': 5, 'list1': {}}]},
 'index2': {'output': [{'quant': 10000.0, 'var1': 22, 'var2': 5, 'list1': {}}]}}
```